# Estimate number of iterations for Taylor Series

Tags: logarithms, taylor-expansion

I'm working with Taylor Series to get the natural logarithm of a number. The series converges faster the closer to **1** is the number to evaluate.

$ln(x) = 2\left[\left( \frac{x-1}{x+1}\right) + \frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right)^3  + \frac{1}{5}\left(\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right)^5 + \frac{1}{7}\left(\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right)^7 ...  + \frac{1}{n}\left(\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right)^n\right]$

Order of the polynomial is $n$.

I'm evaluating numbers $x$ in range $(0.9 , 1.1)$ with a precision of $p$ decimals required. The order of the polynomial $n$ to achieve the precision required would depend on how closer is $x$ to **1**, and the precision $p$.

I want to know is there is a general formula to get the **minimum order of the polynomial** needed to get the number of correct decimals $p$.

For example, $ln(0.95)$ with **7 decimals of precision**:

$ln(0.95) \approx 2\left[\left( \frac{0.95-1}{0.95+1}\right) + \frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{0.95-1}{0.95+1}\right)^3  \right] = 0.0512932....$

The order of the polynomial is $n = 3$.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What you want is a bound on the *remainder* term of the Taylor approximation. You can start on the wiki page for Taylor’s Theorem and look under “Estimates for the remainder”. Also, we normally characterise the approximation by the order of the polynomial (which is simply called the order of the expansion), i.e. $n$ in your example, and not by what you call “iterations”. You could also say “how many terms”.

Comment: You want a bound on the absolute value, so use the version with $M$ on wiki. You can also find many examples of how to use this technique online I’m sure

Comment: @Milten Thanks for your answer, I will take a look at the wiki. I will edit the question replacing "iterations" to "order of the polynomial"

Comment: Actually, your series is not the Taylor series for $\log()$. It uses $\log x = 2\mathrm{artanh}\left(\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right)$, and the series is the Taylor series for $\mathrm{artanh}(x)$ with $\frac{x-1}{x+1}$ plugged in. That means you should get an estimate of how good the $\mathrm{artanh}(x)$ series is, and then translate that to your situation.